# How to include TradingVue charts in python Dash

Tags: python, vue.js, plotly-dash

Is there some way to integrate these type of charts in dash python? It seems that are Vue based charts.

https://github.com/tvjsx/trading-vue-js

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The frontend of Plotly Dash is rendered using React, which makes it relatively straight forward to [create custom Dash components from React components](https://dash.plotly.com/plugins). I would therefore recommend that you find a similar React component and use that instead. Another option would be to [convert the Vue component to React](https://github.com/dwqs/vue-to-react), but I haven't got any experience with it, so I am not sure how well it works.